# How to remove the top rows of an Excel Spreadsheet on Import to a SQL Server Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel

Hello Stack Overflow community. I'm writing a small application in C# that can import an excel file directly into a SQL Database.  I can import files with the current headers that are in the Excel File as they match the column names (See 2nd Image link below) in my Database, however I am looking to add some flexibility to the excel files that I can Import.  Ex: Some of the excel files i need to import have a legend at the top, and this legend does not match the column headers in my database (See 1st image link)

[In this Image you can see the portion of the excel sheet I want to remove **with code**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlEAv.png)

The Files that do not contain that Legend at the top are easily imported

[Without the legend this is where the import can occur at line row 10 in the excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3YZI.png)

I'm looking for a way to remove the top 9 rows (The legend at the top of the file) on import.

Here is all the source code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
using ExcelDataReader;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ProviderBreakfastExcelReader
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

      private void BtnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "Excel Workbook|*.xlsx", ValidateNames = true })
        {
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                var ExcelData = ExcelFileRead(ofd.FileName);
                cboSheet.Items.Clear();
                foreach (DataTable dt in ExcelData.Tables)
                {
                    cboSheet.Items.Add(dt.TableName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private void CboSheet_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = @"C:\Desktop\Dir\filename.xlsx";
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        IExcelDataReader reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
        DataSet result = reader.AsDataSet();
        dataGridView.DataSource = result.Tables[cboSheet.SelectedIndex];
    }

    private DataSet ExcelFileRead(string path)
    {
        using (FileStream fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        using (IExcelDataReader reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(fs))
        {
            var result = reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
            {
                UseColumnDataType = true,
                ConfigureDataTable = (_) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration()
                {
                    EmptyColumnNamePrefix = "Column",
                    UseHeaderRow = true,
                }

            });
            return result;
        }
    }
   private void SendExcelToDatabase(string Filename)
    {
        var data = ExcelFileRead(Filename);
        using (var db = new ProviderBreakfastDBEntities())
        {
            foreach (DataRow record in data.Tables[0].Rows)
            {  
                int rank;
                var isValidRank = int.TryParse(record["Ranking"].ToString(), out rank);
                db.ProviderBreakfastExcels.Add(new ProviderBreakfastExcel
                {   
                    Ranking = isValidRank ? rank : new int?(), 
                    Contact = record["Contact"].ToString(),
                    LastName = record["LastName"].ToString(),
                    FirstName = record["FirstName"].ToString(),
                    // Bedsize = isValidBedsize ? beds : new int?(),
                    Bedsize = Convert.ToInt32(record["Bedsize"].ToString()),
                    City = record["City"].ToString(),
                    Company = record["Company"].ToString(),
                    JobTitle = record["JobTitle"].ToString(),
                    State = record["State"].ToString()
                }); 
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    private void import_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd2 = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (ofd2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string stringFileName = ofd2.FileName;
            textBox1.Text = stringFileName;
            SendExcelToDatabase(stringFileName);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I would use the ExcelReaderFactory  DataSet Method then you can delete the rows from the DataTable.

Comment: Thank you or your response @jdweng, but would you be willing to clarify a bit?

Comment: Use  StartRowPosition =10  in datatable configuration

Comment: Thank you Krishna, but this does not seem to work for me. I get an error that StartRowPosition is not in the current context....

Comment: I looked at source code to find the DataSet method.  Do not have library installed to find exact method.  I think code is GetExcelDataReader(DataReader).AsDataSet()

Comment: I have updated the question will all of the source code now, I should have done that before....I am using ExcelDataReader so i'm not sure why  StartRowPosition is not in the current context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static void GetDataTableFromCsv(string path, bool isFirstRowHeader)
    {
        string header = isFirstRowHeader ? "Yes" : "No";
        string pathOnly = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);
        string sql = @"SELECT [ColumnNamesFromExcelSpreadSheet] FROM [" + fileName + "]";
        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(
                  @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathOnly +
                  ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=" + header + "\""))
        using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection))
        using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command))
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture

            adapter.Fill(dt);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (DataRow dataRow in dt)
            {
                foreach (var item in dataRow.ItemArray)
                {
                    sb.Append(item);
                    sb.Append(',');
                }
            } 
        }
    }
```

This is a great little function for moving an excel spreadsheet into a datatable you can then insert the datatable into your sql db. Only thing you need to change is removing x amount of rows.

EDIT:

```
private void SendExcelToDatabase(string Filename)
{
    int rowThread = HowManyRowsYouWouldLikeToSkipInExcel;
    var data = ExcelFileRead(Filename);
    using (var db = new ProviderBreakfastDBEntities())
    {
        foreach (DataRow record in data.Tables[0].Rows)
        {  
            if (!(rowThreshold >= x))
            {

            int rank;
            var isValidRank = int.TryParse(record["Ranking"].ToString(), out rank);
            db.ProviderBreakfastExcels.Add(new ProviderBreakfastExcel
            {   
                Ranking = isValidRank ? rank : new int?(), 
                Contact = record["Contact"].ToString(),
                LastName = record["LastName"].ToString(),
                FirstName = record["FirstName"].ToString(),
                // Bedsize = isValidBedsize ? beds : new int?(),
                Bedsize = Convert.ToInt32(record["Bedsize"].ToString()),
                City = record["City"].ToString(),
                Company = record["Company"].ToString(),
                JobTitle = record["JobTitle"].ToString(),
                State = record["State"].ToString()
            }); 
        }
      }
        db.SaveChanges();
x++
        }
    }
```

See if something like this works.

Comment: Thank you Digit Plays, much appreciated!

Comment: This would work great if i could use this method.  I appreciate this code very much.  I have to use ExcelDataReader as part of the task.  I have updated my code above to reflect all of the working code now.   Would you be willing to have a look and see if you can help with a solve in the source code above?  Again thank you for your help!

Comment: @PJValentini is the total number of rows to skip always a set amount?

Comment: Yes the that is correct, the first 9 rows can go every time. I will try your updated code.  Thank you for your response!